# Outputing value from backing bean which is an array directly:

Tags: arrays, jsf, iteration

Assuming in my backing bean:

```
 String x []= ....
 public String [] getOutput { return this.x;}

 public String getOutputAsString(){ return Arrays.asString(x);}
```

then in the output page we get the output :

```
#{ myBackingbean.outputAsString }
```

My question is how to eliminate that  `getOutputAsString()` and outputting directly in the ouput page :

I could do just

```
#{ myBackingbean.output[0])
```

but for a looping example ?? Imagine something like

```
for ( i to #{myBackingbean.ouput.length; ){
       #{myBackingbean.ouput [i]; }
    }
```

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a tag or component which can iterate over an array. In standard JSF, that are [`<c:forEach>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/c/forEach.html), [`<ui:repeat>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/repeat.html) and [`<h:dataTable>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/dataTable.html).

1. The `<c:forEach>` runs during [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) and produces JSF components.

   ```
   <c:forEach items="#{bean.array}" var="item">
       #{item}
   </c:forEach>
   ```
2. The `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time and produces no markup.

   ```
   <ui:repeat value="#{bean.array}" var="item">
       #{item}
   </ui:repeat>
   ```
3. The `<h:dataTable>` runs during view render time and produces a HTML `<table>`.

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{bean.array}" var="item">
       <h:column>#{item}</h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
   ```

Comment: and I read on  " the link you provided" , I assume that what you mean by `produces JSF components.` is that `<c:forEach>` producing `<h:ouputText>` by default (even if we don't embed <h:ouputText> directly to the `#{item}`)  right??

Comment: You're welcome. No, it will in the given example produce an `UIInstructions` component.